# Should "How to install Broadcom wireless drivers? (BCM43xx)" be cleaned up?

Tags: discussion, canonical-questions

Seeing as [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/55868/176889) seems to be the main one for all "Broadcom wireless" questions, I believe the question could be cleaned up a bit.

The current question has remnants of what the original OP had tried, and other notes which may not be relevant to the vast majority of people who will read that question.

**Question:** Should [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/q/55868/176889)'s original question post be cleaned up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Yes,

[it is done.](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/55868/23)